# how to do a page to see one new from database and can be searched in google php

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website of news, and i have the next problem: I don´t know how to do a page to see one specific new from my database and people can see the page in google search. I don´t know how to do that, cause the news are in the database, not in a fisical page like html, so google can see it,no? So, that´s my problem, i wanna do a page that recieve a new and can be searched on google too.
Thanks =)

Comment: You should actually try something first before you open a question here. Nobody can code you your results. if you dont know how to implement a simple Page with PHP, you should maybe start with some minor tutorials first before trying to make it SE-Accessible.

Comment: The problem is that i don´t know how websites can have news in google when they don´t have the files in the server. I don´t want the code, only a explanation of how can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"can be searched on google too"** You mean you want to make a web application.If your news are in database, you need to take help from some coding (PHP, ASP.net...etc) to fetch the data and display it in HTML, provided your website is already hosted.
If not, take help from some web hosting service provider.

Comment: And i have to do the file with the information od the new and save the file in the server fisically when someone create the new? Or i have to do only a page like **"new.php"** that make the file temporally generating the page with the database information?